# Is there a way to get css width:auto working when contents flows around a floated element?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div which I need to expand to show the contained text and only wrap the text once the div would exceed the specified max-width. This works fine if the div content is just text but if the text floats around a floating element, the width of the div is calculated as if the floating element were not there. This causes the text to wrap even though the div is well below it's max-width.

See example below with two divs that are identical apart from the second having a floated box in the corner.

Clicking the button repeatedly in the first div correctly causes the div to expand correctly so the text only starts to wrap when the 500px max-width is reached.

When you do the same to the second div the div does not correctly expand to contain the contents without the text wrapping. It appears the div width only increases when the text content reaches the length if it were not flowing around the floated div.

Short of a javascript to calculate and manually adjust the width, is there a way in CSS to make the auto width behave as expected?

```js
function fillDialog(el) {
    var contents = el.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('content');
    var old_html = contents[0].innerHTML;
    contents[0].innerHTML = old_html+" more text";
}
```

```css
#page {
    background:white;
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
    position:relative;
    padding:20px;
}
    
.dialog {
    position: relative;
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    border: 2px black solid;
    margin-top:20px;
    padding:20px;
    min-height:120px;
    width:auto;
    min-width:200px;
    max-width:500px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
    
.modalButton {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}
    
.icon {
    float:left;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:cornflowerblue;
    margin:0px 10px 10px 0px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px black solid;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="page">
        <div style="width:200px; float:left; background-color: #999;">200px</div>
        <div style="width:300px; float:left; background-color: #BBB;">500px</div>
        
        <div class="dialog">
            <button class="modalButton" type="button" onclick="fillDialog(this)">Add text</button>
            <div class="content">Content
            </div> <!-- close content -->
        </div> <!-- close dialog -->
        
        <div class="dialog">
            <button class="modalButton" type="button" onclick="fillDialog(this)">Add text</button>
            <div class="icon"> ! </div>
            <div class="content">Content
            </div> <!-- close content -->
        </div> <!-- close dialog -->
        
    </div> <!-- close page -->
```

Comment: Please move all your inline styles out to your stylesheet. No one likes trying to rectify styles from two locations.

Comment: Actually, at least when I run your snippet, the div does start to expand well before the full text that would fill one line is created. It’s as if there is some balancing of words being done. What browser/OS are you on?

Comment: I very much doubt it. This is one of a class of problems stemming from the shrink-to-fit algorithm. The order is - compute the preferred container width from the max text width. The container is oblivious to the out-of-flow float. Then shorten the line box to avoid the float but stay within the container. (i.e. the line box is float-aware, but the container isn't.) Then fragment the text into the line boxes. I can't see where the sequence could be manipulated to overcome the issue.

Comment: Just to note that your measuring divs don’t work when on a narrow viewport, the 500px goes below the 200px but it needs to abut it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use display flex to get what you want.

```js
function fillDialog(el) {
    var contents = el.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('content');
    var old_html = contents[0].innerHTML;
    contents[0].innerHTML = old_html+" more text";
}
```

```css
#page {

background: white;
width: 100%;
height: 600px;
position: relative;
padding: 20px;

}

.dialog {

  width: fit-content;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px black solid;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 120px;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}

.modalButton {

  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;

}

.icon {

  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;

}
```

```html
    <div id="page">
        <div style="width:200px; float:left; background-color: #999;">200px</div>
        <div style="width:300px; float:left; background-color: #BBB;">500px</div>
        
        <div class="dialog">
            <button class="modalButton" type="button" onclick="fillDialog(this)">Add text</button>
            <div class="content">Content
            </div> <!-- close content -->
        </div> <!-- close dialog -->
        
        <div class="dialog">
            <button class="modalButton" type="button" onclick="fillDialog(this)">Add text</button>
            <div class="icon"> ! </div>
            <div class="content">Content
            </div> <!-- close content -->
        </div> <!-- close dialog -->
        
    </div> <!-- close page -->
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to provide this solution. I was not familiar with display flex. I need the site to work with fairly old browsers so in this instance I’ve gone for a JavaScript solution but it’s prompted me to learn more about flex options for the future.